# Formatted USB drive, not detecting...repairable?

Tags: partitioning, usb-drive

I formatted my pendrive with ext2 filesystem in ubuntu.Now its not detecting in ubuntu and windows.

Here's what the disk utility says.

```
Model: GENERIC USB Mass Stoarge
Firmware Version: 1.00
Location: -
Write Cache: -
Capacity: No Media Detected
Partitoning: -
Serial Number:
World Wide Name: -
Device: /dev/sdb
Rotation Rate: -
Connection: USB at 480.0 MB/s
SMART status: Not Supported

Options... 
Format Drive -- Safe Removal

Volumes: - 
Usage: -
Device: 
Partition type: -
Capacity: -
```

Then click on format drive and try to format with every option, its showing some error like:

> Error creating partition table: helper exited with exit code 1: cannot
>   open /dev/sdb: No medium found

Then I tried GParted to format USB drive, but it is not detecting. How can I repair these usb drive?

Result of following commands:

```
$ sudo cfdisk /dev/sdb
FATAL ERROR: Cannot open disk drive Press any key to exit cfdisk 

$ sudo mkfs.ext2 /dev/sdb 
mke2fs 1.41.14 (22-Dec-2010) 
/dev/sdb is entire device, not just one partition! Proceed anyway? (y,n) y 
mkfs.ext2: No medium found while trying to determine filesystem size 

$ sudo mkfs.vfat /dev/sdb 
mkfs.vfat 3.0.9 (31 Jan 2010)
/dev/sdb: No medium found
```

Comment: If the format drive option is available i guess you can format it again in a filesystem compatable with both linux and windows(i.e. FAT or NTFS).
Windows cannot detect any ext(1,2,3,4) filesystem.
Though Ubuntu should have detected it.May be the formating did not succed properly.

Comment: Formatting showing some error like  - Error creating partition table: helper exited with exit code 1: cannot open /dev/sdb: No medium found

Comment: Then you didn't format it after all. If you are *sure *that's exactly the error message you got, you should edit your question to include it. Otherwise, try formatting it again, and assuming it fails again, copy the full and exact text of your error message and add it to your question.

Comment: /dev/sdb is a  device. First of all you need create partition on this device (you can do that using `sudo cfdisk /dev/sdb`). Then, you can create filesystem on it (`sudo mkfs.ext2 /dev/sdb1` or `sudo mkfs.vfat /dev/sdb1`).

Comment: result of following commands:      sudo cfdisk /dev/sdb)           FATAL ERROR: Cannot open disk drive
                          Press any key to exit cfdisk           $ sudo mkfs.ext2 /dev/sdb
mke2fs 1.41.14 (22-Dec-2010)
/dev/sdb is entire device, not just one partition!
Proceed anyway? (y,n) y
mkfs.ext2: No medium found while trying to determine filesystem size
$ sudo mkfs.vfat /dev/sdb
mkfs.vfat 3.0.9 (31 Jan 2010)
/dev/sdb: No medium found

Comment: I would use `gparted` to create a new `MBR` on the device. This will ensure any poorly created partitions are completely gone.